# Paramater passing with text in C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

O have an assignment in which I must create a function to prompt a user for a filename and pass the input back to main. I must pass it as a parameter (I'm assuming this means pass-by-reference.) I am simply working on the first function "getFileName." I know there are easier ways to do this in C++, but I am instructed to do it this way, I'm sure there is something valuable to learn here but I'm not grasping it. In any case I was able to get the function to work with integers as such:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

void getFileName(int &fileName);

int main()
{
   int fileName;
   getFileName(fileName);
   cout << fileName;
   return 0;
}

void getFileName(int &fileName)
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   return;
}
```

My problem arrises when I try to change the integers to text. I am told to use the prototype:

```
void getFileName(char []);
```

Everything I try gives me errors, mostly to do with setting pointers to arrays, or setting reference to arrays and so on. My current code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getFileName(char &fileName[]);

int main()
{
   char fileName[];
   getFileName(fileName);
   cout << fileName;
   return 0;
}
void getFileName(char &fileName)
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   return;
}
```

And I get errors with g++:

```
assign26.cpp:19: error: declaration of ‘fileName’ as array of references
assign26.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
assign26.cpp:23: error: storage size of ‘fileName’ isn't known
```

While giving me the code to fix the problem will help me get my assignment done, I do want to understand what is happening, so please explain solutions. I greatly appreciate all help given.

***EDIT***

Here is the code that works, thanks to members of this site for all the help!

```
void getFileName(char fileName[]);

int main()
{
   char fileName[256];
   getFileName(fileName);
   cout << fileName;
   return 0;
}

void getFileName(char fileName[])
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   return;
}
```

The problem: I did not understand how an array functions. I was trying to pass text by reference when I did not need to. Also syntax errors which I should have seen.

Comment: `char& fileName[]` is declared as an array of references to a char. The standard says there can't be array of references. But you don't need this to accomplish what you're doing anyway.

Comment: The `storage size of 'fileName' isn't known` is just because you don't specify a size here `char fileName[];`.

Comment: The signatures of your prototype and implementation do not match. That's another problem.

Comment: Why not use `string` for fileName and `string&` as reference for the function?

Comment: Thanks for the help! After solving these syntax errors, I still had errors, the below response about an array doing what I want it to do solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the prototype of your function does not match the signature of its implementation. You probably think `char& x[]` is the same as `char& x` in the parameter list but they are actually very different. The first declares an array of reference to a character and the last declares a reference to a character. An array of references is disallowed by the Standard so that isn't possible, and passing an array by reference (which I suspect you were trying to do) isn't needed in this situation.

In your post you said you wanted to insert text. If this is the case all you need is an array of characters. Your signature should now look something like:

```
void getFileName(char fileName[]);
```

Furthermore, inside main you declare an array `fileName` of unknown bound. This isn't allowed as you *must* specify the dimension. Something like:

```
char fileName[256];
```

But if you don't know how many characters will be entered by the user you should dynamically-allocate the array. For example, use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

void getFileName(std::string &);

int main()
{
    std::string fileName;
    getFileName(fileName);
}

void getFileName(std::string& fileName)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
    std::cin >> fileName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I wasn't aware that simply creating the array would have a similar effect as passing an integer by reference.

Comment: @user2443549 You're not passing an integer by reference. This is an array of *`char`*.

Comment: @user2443549 Are you confused about something? Are you having any more problems?

Comment: I understand that I am not passing an integer by reference, as I was working through this, I assumed I would need to do something similar. We have not covered arrays, and I was trying to pass text by reference, when creating an array is the proper solution. I was making things more complicated. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory for the fileName. So the file name won't fit in that (zero length) buffer. You need something like

char fileName[256];

Also, your function prototype for getFileName does not match the function itself. Make both parameter lists the same.